# Why can't I set a member value for a class instance?

Tags: c++

I am confused about this problem output result:

**I am 10 years old. My name is**

Why there is blank string after "My name is"?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Name {
    int first_name;
    int last_name;

public:
    void setName(int f, int l) {
        first_name = f;
        last_name = l;
    }

    int true_name(){
        first_name + last_name;
    }
};

class Persion {

public:
    int age;
    Name name;

    Persion(){

    }

public:
    void hello(void){
        cout << "I am ";
        cout << age;
        cout << " years old.";
        cout << " My name is " + name.true_name() << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Persion a;
    Name name;
    name.setName(10, 2);
    a.age = 10;
    a.name = name;
    a.hello();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `return` statement in `true_name`.  I would think the compiler would at least warn you about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

```
int true_name(){
    first_name + last_name;
}
```

means "add first_name and last_name, discard the result (because you neither returned it nor assigned it to a variable), then return some random result (likely whatever happened to most recently be in the appropriate CPU register)."

Your compiler should have given you warning messages explaining this.  For example, GCC gives the following warnings:

```
warning: statement has no effect
warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

Make sure that warnings are enabled for your compiler (for example, in GCC, use `-Wall` from the command line) and pay attention to the warnings.

You should have used something like this:

```
int true_name(){
    return first_name + last_name;
}
```

The next problem is in this line:

```
cout << " My name is " + name.true_name() << endl;
```

" My name is " is a `const char *` (pointer to char array, not a `std::string` class instance), and adding an integer to a pointer means to index that pointer.  In this case, you're saying "go true_name() characters into " My name is " and start printing from there."  Do this instead:

```
cout << " My name is " << name.true_name() << endl;
```

Also, it's "Person," not "Persion."

Comment: Very thanks. Should I declare "Name name;" in Person class to "Name *name;" or not? How to think about this point?

Comment: @qichunren - In C++ OO, "Name name;" means "a Person owns a Name and is responsible for it and always has a Name and has exactly one Name."  "Name *name;" can mean a few things; "a Person may or may not have a Name" or "a Person has a reference to a Name somewhere else but does not own it" or "a Person owns a Name, which is polymorphic."  (I'm simplifying here some.)  "A Person owns a Name and is responsible for it and always has a Name and has exactly one Name" is what you want, so use "Name name;".

Comment: Thanks very much. You explain it in plain language, very straightaway.